# One button performs two tasks, need to call second function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a trivia game and I'm stuck on the very last part. I am displaying all of the correct, incorrect, unanswered questions.

```
function displayResults() {
    $('#timer').html("Correct answers: " + correct);
    $('#fiveSec').html("Incorrect answers: " + incorrect);
    $('#question').html("Unaswered: " + unanswered);
    $('#correct-answer').empty();
    $('#answers').append('<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" "start-button" value="Play Again">');
}
```

At the end of this function, inside of the button, I need to have a way for this function that starts the game to run again.

```
$('#start-button').on('click', function() {
    currentQuestion = 0;
    correct = 0;
    incorrect = 0;
    unanswered = 0;
    count = 30;
    five = 5;
    currentTeamsLength = 0;
    displayQuestion();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

So this `#start-button` is the same button that started the game and I want to run it over again inside of the `displayResults` once the game is finished. Any ideas?

Comment: "start-button" looks like it's missing the id attribute.

Comment: yea i realized that after submitted this but it didn't change anything. there's something i have to do within that line that will point it back to the beginning and run that $('#start-button').on('click', funciton() over again. it's driving me crazy right now. literally the last thing i have to do and im done. its also not giving me any errors, its just when that final page loads with the playagain button and i click on it, nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `re-trigger` the game with `click` event from `displayQuestions()` as follows,

```
$('.start-button').trigger('click');
```

Please fix you button as follows,

```
$('#answers').append('<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary start-button" value="Play Again">');
```

Also you need to bind the click event with delegation method,

```
$("#answers").on('click', '.start-button', function(){
      // your code logic
});
```

You need use class selector as there is no id on button.

Comment: i was told there is something in this line..$('#answers').append('<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" "start-button" value="Play Again">');  that is missing and it's keeping the game from running again when you click on it

Comment: that doesn't work. i was told the there is something within this line ... $('#answers').append('<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" "start-button" value="Play Again">');   that im missing that is keeping it from running

Comment: @noobDevel_up_er  try updated answer. You need to fix your button also you dont have id so dont use # to select but use .

Answer (score 0):

Jsut make a new function like this

```
 $('#start-button').on('click', startGame)

 function startGame(){
     currentQuestion = 0;
     correct = 0;
     incorrect = 0;
     unanswered = 0;
     count = 30; 
     five = 5;
     currentTeamsLength = 0;
     displayQuestion();
     $(this).remove();
});
```

And call this function from displayResults

Or

You can manually trigger click in displayResult like

```
 $('#start-button').trigger("click")
```

Comment: You could seperate this from the function and just bind the event to all "#start-button" elements added to the page with a .on();

Answer (score 0):

Change button text when it is first pressed, then based on button text you can put an If condition and then execute another function. 
*(I hope this was what you were asking, your question is not very clear)*

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Dumb mistake by me. All it was in    $('#answers').append('');    i did not need a # in id='#start-button'. after that i changed   $('#start-button').on('click', function()   to     $(document).on('click', 'start-button' function()    then i had to clear some divs in the displayResults function